How can I optimize fuzzy matching for large datasets in Python?
I have two files:

Input_file.xlsx - containing 9,008 rows and 7 columns.
CP_Data.xlsx - containing 149,987 rows and 7 columns.

I need to perform fuzzy matching between these two files as efficiently and accurately as possible, with a focus on achieving a balanced distribution.
The Challenges:

Performance Issue: When I reduce the data size to around 3,000 rows for each file, the process executes successfully in approximately 15 seconds in VS Code. However, when I increase the row count to around 4,000, the process hangs on “Processing...” without any clear indication if it’s still running.

Execution Time: I need to improve the execution speed and ensure that it can handle the full data sizes more efficiently.
If anyone has a solution to optimize this process, both in terms of speed and scalability, I would greatly appreciate it.


https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cleardatalab/Royalty-Network/main/Fuzzy%20Matching%20V3/Main_code.py
This is my code.
